# Teenage girl who falls in love with a dead boy

Tags: story-identification, books, zombie

I remember the book being about a girl who's in high school. I'm not sure if all dead come back to life but definitely the teenagers, and it's almost as if they coexist. I think she falls in love with one of these dead boys. They definitely all seem to go to school together.

At the time I loved the *Fallen* series by Lauren Kate, and this was another random book I really enjoyed but I can't remember the name and I'm endlessly searching.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 2):

Zombie/non-metabolically-challenged pairings seem to have become a bit of a trope in the past decade or so, but based on the specific details of your question I think you're probably remembering [*Generation Dead*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?877234) (2008) by Daniel Waters.  It fits your time frame because the first *Fallen* book was published in 2009.

The protagonist is Phoebe, a high-school student in a world where for some reason teenagers who die come back as zombies (or "differently biotic"), but are otherwise mostly like themselves before and still want to have friends, hang out, go to school, etc.  Phoebe finds herself drawn to Tommy Williams, one of her "living impaired" classmates.

[image: Cover of "Generation Dead" with a zombie cheerleader lying on a bench]

You can read a longer description of the book on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Dead), and there are more details in the reviews on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3157877-generation-dead).